# Deleting N nodes after M nodes in a Singly Linked List

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Given a linked list, delete N nodes after skipping M nodes of a linked list until the last of the linked list

This is the Java program I wrote to solve this problem. For certain large test cases it's showing error,
"*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot assign field "next" because "" is null
at SinglyLinkedList.deleteNNodesAfterEveryMNodes(DeleteNNodesAfterMNodesOfALinkedList.java:88)
at DeleteNNodesAfterMNodesOfALinkedList.main(DeleteNNodesAfterMNodesOfALinkedList.java:127)*"

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Link
{
    public int data;
    public Link next;

    public Link(int d)
    {
        data = d;
    }

    public void displayLink()
    {
        System.out.print(data + " ");
    }
}

class SinglyLinkedList
{
    public Link first;

    public SinglyLinkedList()
    {
        first = null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return(first == null);
    }

    public void insertLast(int d)
    {
        Link nl = new Link(d);

        if(isEmpty())
        {
            first = nl;
        }

        else
        {
            Link curr = first;

            while(curr.next != null)
            {
                curr = curr.next;
            }

            curr.next = nl;
        }
    }

    public void displayList()
    {
        Link curr = first;

        while(curr != null)
        {
            curr.displayLink();
            curr = curr.next;
        }
    }

    public void deleteNNodesAfterEveryMNodes(int N, int M)
    {
        Link curr1=first, curr2=first;

        int n=N+M, m=M;

        while(curr1!=null && curr1.next!=null)
        {
            while(curr2!=null && n!=0)
            {
                if(m != 1)
                {
                    curr1 = curr1.next;
                    m--;
                }

                curr2 = curr2.next;
                n--;
            }


            curr1.next = curr2;

            m = M;
            n = N+M;
            curr1 = curr2;
        }
    }
}

class DeleteNNodesAfterMNodesOfALinkedList
{
    public static void main(String st[])
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        SinglyLinkedList sll = new SinglyLinkedList();

        int count, d, N, M;

        System.out.println("Enter the number of integers you want to store in the singly linked list: ");
        count = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("\nEnter the " + count + " integers: ");
        for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
        {
            d = sc.nextInt();
            sll.insertLast(d);
        }

        System.out.println("\nThe singly linked list is: ");
        sll.displayList();

        System.out.println("\n\nEnter the value of 'M', the number of nodes to be skipped: ");
        M = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("\nEnter the value of 'N', the number of nodes now to be deleted: ");
        N = sc.nextInt();


        sll.deleteNNodesAfterEveryMNodes(N, M);

        System.out.println("\nThe resultant singly linked list is: ");
        sll.displayList();
    }
}
```

I can't figure out what went wrong and how is assigning curr1.next = curr2; is of any issue at line 127

Comment: How about writing a function to delete a node. Then skipping m times using while or for loop, then call the delete function n times using another loop or till the end of linked list is reached. Also please either pass First as an argument. or use this keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You can either try to put an additional check of curr1!=null in the second while loop or simplify the problem.

Simplifying the problem can be done by:

1. Using a for loop (m number of times) to traverse the list.
2. Using another for loop (n number of times) to call a piece of code that deletes the nodes one by one.

Also check for edge conditions i.e. if m + n < size and so on.